# How to handle RESOURCE EXHAUSTED error in API calls

Tags: daml

I’m using the Java Ledger Bindings to get packages from the ledger via the Package service and am getting the following error:

`RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: gRPC message exceeds maximum size`

My application is based on the Ping-Pong example application and the daml model has about 300+ daml files.

The exception occurs around the following code block:

```
DamlLedgerClient client = DamlLedgerClient.forHostWithLedgerIdDiscovery(host, port, Optional.empty());
client.connect();
PackageClient packageService = client.getPackageClient();
Flowable<String> packagesIds = packageService.listPackages();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message size is limited by the `ManagedChannel` used to connect to the gRPC server. To increase it, you have to construct and configure the `ManagedChannel` for gRPC yourself and pass it to the constructor of `DamlLedgerClient`.

```
ManagedChannel channel =
    ManagedChannelBuilder
    .forAddress(host,port)
    .usePlaintext()
    .maxInboundMessageSize(9999999)
    .build();
DamlLedgerClient client = new DamlLedgerClient(Optional.empty(), channel);
```